# Javascript Bug Report

Tags: javascript, debugging, bug-reporting

Is there any javascript framework for reporting bugs?

I'd like to be able to get a copy of the web page the user is currently looking at plus maybe a stack trace on the JS, their current browser etc. and post it to my web application so that when I try to debug the application I spend less time trying to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExceptionHub](http://www.exceptionhub.com) is a service that might be what you're looking for. There is some overhead as it wraps the calls to `addEventListener`, `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, etc. with try catch blocks to get stacktraces.

There isn't a way to get a screenshot of the page without using escalated privileges or a browser extension. The canvas element in Mozilla's implementation has a [`drawWindow` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas) that can render the current window to a canvas element, with that you could post the pixel data.

Comment: Actually I was just looking for the html and css rather than a screenshot which ExceptionHub doesn't seem to support. Also you have to pay for it, which I don't really want to do.